# Python error when trying to run docker-compose up

Tags: python, docker, python-2.7, docker-compose, pip

I have installed docker-compose via ansible and I am trying to run a `docker-compose up` command but I am getting the error below:

```
sudo cd /etc/project/compose/ && docker-compose up -vvv

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 7, in <module>
    from compose.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ..config import ConfigurationError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/config/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .config import ConfigurationError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/config/config.py", line 51, in <module>
    from .validation import match_named_volumes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/config/validation.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jsonschema import Draft4Validator
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonschema/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from jsonschema._types import TypeChecker
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonschema/_types.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyrsistent import pmap
ImportError: cannot import name pmap
```

I'm confused around the message `ImportError: cannot import name pmap`

When I run sudo `pip install pmap` it looks like it's already installed so confused as to why the docker compose error is passing that.

```
Requirement already satisfied: pmap in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: wsgiref==0.1.2 in /usr/lib64/python2.7 (from pmap)
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 23.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command
```

Been going around in circles with this, does anyone have suggestions as to why that is happening?

Results of pip list;

```
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
attrs (21.4.0)
awscli (1.23.2)
Babel (0.9.6)
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size (1.0.0)
backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.5.0.1)
bcrypt (3.1.7)
boto (2.45.0)
cached-property (1.5.2)
certifi (2021.10.8)
cffi (1.6.0)
chardet (4.0.0)
Cheetah (2.4.4)
cloud-init (19.4)
configobj (4.7.2)
configparser (4.0.2)
contextlib2 (0.6.0.post1)
cryptography (3.3.2)
decorator (3.4.0)
distlib (0.3.6)
distro (1.6.0)
docker (4.3.1)
docker-compose (1.26.0)
docker-py (1.1.0)
dockerpty (0.4.1)
docopt (0.6.2)
docutils (0.11)
enum34 (1.0.4)
filelock (3.2.1)
functools32 (3.2.3.post2)
futures (3.4.0)
idna (2.10)
importlib-metadata (2.1.3)
importlib-resources (3.3.1)
iniparse (0.4)
ipaddress (1.0.16)
IPy (0.75)
javapackages (1.0.0)
Jinja2 (2.7.2)
jmespath (0.10.0)
jsonpatch (1.2)
jsonpointer (1.9)
jsonschema (3.2.0)
kitchen (1.1.1)
lxml (3.2.1)
Markdown (2.4.1)
MarkupSafe (0.11)
paramiko (2.12.0)
pathlib2 (2.3.7.post1)
perf (0.1)
Pillow (2.0.0)
pip (9.0.3)
platformdirs (2.0.2)
ply (3.4)
pmap (0.0.6)
policycoreutils-default-encoding (0.1)
prettytable (0.7.2)
py-pmap (0.1.1)
pyasn1 (0.1.9)
pycparser (2.14)
pycurl (7.19.0)
Pygments (1.4)
pygobject (3.22.0)
pygpgme (0.3)
pyliblzma (0.5.3)
PyNaCl (1.4.0)
pyrsistent (0.17.2)
pyserial (2.6)
python-dateutil (1.5)
python-dotenv (0.18.0)
python-linux-procfs (0.4.9)
pyudev (0.15)
pyxattr (0.5.1)
PyYAML (3.10)
requests (2.27.1)
rsa (3.4.2)
s3transfer (0.1.13)
scandir (1.10.0)
schedutils (0.4)
seobject (0.1)
sepolicy (1.1)
setuptools (0.9.8)
singledispatch (3.7.0)
six (1.4.0)
slip (0.4.0)
slip.dbus (0.4.0)
subprocess32 (3.5.4)
texttable (1.6.7)
typing (3.10.0.0)
urlgrabber (3.10)
urllib3 (1.26.15)
virtualenv (20.15.1)
websocket-client (0.59.0)
yum-metadata-parser (1.1.4)
zipp (1.2.0)
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 23.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

```
sudo pip --version
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

```
sudo /usr/bin/python2.7 -m pip list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
attrs (21.4.0)
awscli (1.23.2)
Babel (0.9.6)
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size (1.0.0)
backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.5.0.1)
bcrypt (3.1.7)
boto (2.45.0)
cached-property (1.5.2)
certifi (2021.10.8)
cffi (1.6.0)
chardet (4.0.0)
Cheetah (2.4.4)
cloud-init (19.4)
configobj (4.7.2)
configparser (4.0.2)
contextlib2 (0.6.0.post1)
cryptography (3.3.2)
decorator (3.4.0)
distlib (0.3.6)
distro (1.6.0)
docker (4.3.1)
docker-compose (1.26.0)
docker-py (1.1.0)
dockerpty (0.4.1)
docopt (0.6.2)
docutils (0.11)
enum34 (1.0.4)
filelock (3.2.1)
functools32 (3.2.3.post2)
futures (3.4.0)
idna (2.10)
importlib-metadata (2.1.3)
importlib-resources (3.3.1)
iniparse (0.4)
ipaddress (1.0.16)
IPy (0.75)
javapackages (1.0.0)
Jinja2 (2.7.2)
jmespath (0.10.0)
jsonpatch (1.2)
jsonpointer (1.9)
jsonschema (3.2.0)
kitchen (1.1.1)
lxml (3.2.1)
Markdown (2.4.1)
MarkupSafe (0.11)
paramiko (2.12.0)
pathlib2 (2.3.7.post1)
perf (0.1)
Pillow (2.0.0)
pip (9.0.3)
platformdirs (2.0.2)
ply (3.4)
pmap (0.0.6)
policycoreutils-default-encoding (0.1)
prettytable (0.7.2)
py-pmap (0.1.1)
pyasn1 (0.1.9)
pycparser (2.14)
pycurl (7.19.0)
Pygments (1.4)
pygobject (3.22.0)
pygpgme (0.3)
pyliblzma (0.5.3)
PyNaCl (1.4.0)
pyrsistent (0.17.2)
pyserial (2.6)
python-dateutil (1.5)
python-dotenv (0.18.0)
python-linux-procfs (0.4.9)
pyudev (0.15)
pyxattr (0.5.1)
PyYAML (3.10)
requests (2.27.1)
rsa (3.4.2)
s3transfer (0.1.13)
scandir (1.10.0)
schedutils (0.4)
seobject (0.1)
sepolicy (1.1)
setuptools (0.9.8)
singledispatch (3.7.0)
six (1.4.0)
slip (0.4.0)
slip.dbus (0.4.0)
subprocess32 (3.5.4)
texttable (1.6.7)
typing (3.10.0.0)
urlgrabber (3.10)
urllib3 (1.26.15)
virtualenv (20.15.1)
websocket-client (0.59.0)
yum-metadata-parser (1.1.4)
zipp (1.2.0)
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 23.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Can you check (and maybe add to your question) the versions of `jsonschema` and `pyrsistent` ?

Comment: I'm asking because I've seen this sort of behavior with requirements mismatches. Imagine that a developer creates the `super-duper-pkg` depending on `packageA`. At the time, the latest version of `packageA` is 3, so the developer of `super-duper-package` writes `packageA > 3`. Years later, version 4 of packageA is created. It changes the imports, naming... HUGE change. You have installed `packageA, version 4`. Then you try to install `super-duper-pkg`. Is the requirement of `packageA > 3` fulfilled? Yes! It's version `4`! But now `super-duper-pkg` breaks because `packageA` changed a lot.

Comment: Where is your Dockerfile? requirements.txt file? docker-compose.yml file? can you share them?

Comment: You're using Python 2.7; or rather, docker-compose is. At a guess, the pyrsistent version that is compatible with 2.7 doesn't contain the pmap module. Can you do a `pip list` and list the version of pyrsistent that is installed?

Comment: @9769953 I've added the versions of pip packages.

Comment: A few things to note: 1/ pyrsistent 0.17.2 was yanked from pypi, so probably shouldn't be used. 2/ pyrsistent requires Python 3.5 or later. 3/ there is no compose package.

Comment: One possible conclusion is that the pip you are using is not the one that belongs to /usr/bin/python2.7. Try `pip --version`, then try `/usr/bin/python2.7 -m pip list` to ensure you're using the correct pip, and check if the output is the same (or does actually contain the compose package).

Comment: Correction: I think the compose package is listed as docker-compose. The annoyance of package names not having to be the same as their import name.

Comment: @9769953 output added

Comment: Everything seems to be there, and pip & Python match. That's not the issue then.

Comment: Related GitHub issues for pyrsistent: https://github.com/tobgu/pyrsistent/issues/208 and https://github.com/tobgu/pyrsistent/issues/207 (directly next to each other; see the numbers), and the latter has a pointer to https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/71678 . These are not the exact same error, but it seems very related.

Comment: It's a bit hard to find the exact history, but it looks like there were some dependency version requirement issues (which is why pyrsistent versions 0.17.{0,1,2} were yanked from pypi), all related to transitioning away from Python 2.7. I don't know how you installed docker-compose: that is, how you set it up in your Ansible file. That would be the next thing to look at: the Ansible file that is responsible for setting up docker-compose, and specifically anything about the version or dependency requirements.

Comment: Issue was resolved by removing everything and starting again on a clean EC2. I think the issue had been down to previous versions of packages left on the box that got in the way of deploying what we needed.

Answer (score 1):

Closed - No real resolution other than building a brand new EC2 that had no previous packages installed on it.